# GET other device token value using IBM Cloud in Watson IoT

Tags: ibm-cloud, token, watson-iot

I'm testing Watson IoT using IBM Cloud.

I registered two device to IBM Cloud, and was issued each token value.
(A, B device and A, B token value)

So, I want to GET other device's token value, (from A device to B device)

Is it Possible ?
I think that it can not possible, because device token value can not check IBM Cloud Dashboard.

Is it right? I attached figure explained question. please give your advise. 
Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVd69.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Getting a device's token is not possible: when devices are registered, their tokens are salted and hashed. This means they cannot be recovered from Watson IoT Platform in any way - this is by secure design. (If you have lost your device's token, the only way to restore connectivity is to re-register the device to get a new token).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks your advise!